# Is object initialization atomic in Java?

Tags: java, atomic

I know `myObject1 = myObject2` is atomic, but is following line of code atomic?

```
Object obj1 = new Object();
```

Can it actually be suspended in the middle of initializing a reference?

Comment: Are you worried about `obj1` being observed as an invalid reference, or about the reference to the object being observed earlier than the initialization of the fields of the object, or something else?

Comment: "Atomic" can mean a few different things depending on the context. What is the context or the scenario here? Are multiple thread involved?

Comment: Yeah I meant on multible threads. Didn't know there were other concepts..All I know is atomic operation :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is not atomic. Two things happen: first, new `Object` is created (which is in general is not atomic), and then the reference to this object is assigned to the variable `obj1`. Say, the line executed by `Thread1`, and `Thread2` observes the state of the variable at a random moment. There are three states `Thread2` can observe (for simplicity assume object creation itself is atomic),

1. `obj1 == null`, the object is not created
2. `obj1 == null`, the object is created, but the reference to it is yet to be assigned to the variable
3. `obj1 != null`, the line is fully executed

Atomicity would suggest that `Thread2` may observe only state 1 and 3, but it has to be enforced. One way to make it atomic is via synchronization (in this example `obj1` is a class field):

```
public synchronized Object getObj() {
    if (obj1 == null)
        obj1 = new Object();

    return obj1;
}
```

First thread calling this method will initialize the field, and further calls will simply return the variable. Due to mutual exclusion, it is not possible for a thread to observe `null` in `obj1` after the object is created, since method calls by different threads cannot overlap.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense :) You made me curious now when you said that just object creating is not atomic. I never though about that..

Comment: There is also a 4th state allowed by the Java memory model: `obj1 != null` but the constructor has not finished. This is possible thanks to out-of-order execution

Comment: @Joni Yep, races are pure evil!

Answer (score 4):

It is not atomic. There's nothing stopping you from putting a `sleep` inside the Object constructor, or an infinite loop, or throwing an exception inside the constructor.

**NOTE:** Although possible, these are all anti-patterns and are not recommended.

Comment: Throwing an exception inside a constructor isn't exactly an antipattern, but your point stands.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense indeed. Would it be atomic if there was empty constructor?

Answer (score 2):

The reference assignment is atomic. There is no condition under which the reference itself will be partly assigned (this would obviously cause the VM to crash at times). It will either be null or not-null. The *construction* of the object before the reference is assigned isn't atomic, but you won't get access to the new object to assign to the reference until the construction process is finished.

Interestingly, the reference assignment can occur in cached memory on the chip that isn't synchronized with main memory. This means other threads won't see the assignment right away. There are two ways to ensure that the reference assignment is pushed through to main memory where other threads can immediately see it. (1) declare the reference as volatile and (2) put the reference assignment in a synchronized block (exiting the synchronized block will commit the cached reference to main memory)